# CKEditor, initialize widget added with insertElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, ckeditor, contenteditable

I have some widgets created, they on initial startup they load fine, but i add more of this type of widget to the editor through:

```
ckeditorInstance.insertElement(
        CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<html></html>'));
```

It inserts just fine, but the ckeditor does not recognize the element inserted as a widget, so the widget editable fields are not getting enabled like they should.

Is there any way to make ckeditor do a rescan of its content to initialize any new widgets that it has not already initialized?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Data formats

First of all - there's a separation for data format of a widget (how widget is represented in data) and internal format (how it is represented in editor). You may be familiar with the [upcast](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast) and [downcast](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-downcast) functions - they make the transition between those formats (upcasting means transforming data format to internal format).

Upcasting and downcasting work only if data **string** is processed, but if you insert content using `editor#insertElement` there's no processing, so there's no upcasting.

### Inserting

You've got two solutions:

1. Use [`editor#insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) instead of `editor#insertElement`. Your widget will be upcasted before insertion, so it will be inserted in a good format.
2. Take care of upcasting (if needed) yourself and use `editor#insertElement`.

### Initializing

This was a first step of widget's life - it has to be inserted. Second is to be initialized.

1. **There's a [bug](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11171) currently** (it will be fixed in two weeks), that widgets inserted by the `insertHtml` method are not initialized. So, at this moment, after inserting widget with `editor#insertHtml` you need to call:

   [`editor.widgets.checkWidgets()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-checkWidgets)
2. If you use `editor#insertElement` you need to take care of initializing widget. To do that call:

   [`editor.widgets.initOn( element, 'widgetName' )`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-initOn)

In both scenarios **initialize widget after inserting it**.

Check out the [Widgets API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget) for more details.

See also my answer [explaining how to know if an element is a widget and how to insert them into editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636920/how-to-tell-if-an-element-is-a-widget-ckeditor/29645073#29645073).

Comment: Thanks alot Reinmar! Used your first alternative and it worked like it should. Also extra credits for the explaining the answer in such a good way.

Comment: When using insertElement/initOn, is it expected that you've already manually upcasted the widget and inserted the full HTML for it?

Comment: Yes, `insertElement` does not process content (element cannot be parsed, because reference to it would be lost), so you need to insert element in the upcasted form.

Comment: Hi @Reinmar, I have a question, can I call a widget from Richcombo?  So, when one of the dropdown menu is clicked, it will insert a widget to the editor. I've asked this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475998/ckeditor-4-3-widget-richcombo 
Thanks!

Comment: @Reinmar How can you tell if an element is a widget or destined to become one? I asked this question here as a follow up to this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636920/how-to-tell-if-an-element-is-a-widget-ckeditor

Comment: I don't usually use 5 year old answers, but when i do... it's when i work with CKEditor stuff. Thank you, i could not why I could not `upcast` automatically when using `insertElement` event.

Comment: That's right... CKEditor 4 widgets are 5 years old. Still no other RTE I know rolled out a similar feature :) Actually, except CKEditor 5 which pushed the concept of widgets even further :)