# Insert HTML before an element in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

What is the best way to programmatically insert HTML (that represents a CKEditor widget) before an existing element in CKEditor?

The content editable is not in focus and is not currently being edited.

For example, suppose the contents of the editor are:

```
<h1>Here's a title</h1>
<h2>Here's a subtitle</h2>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
<p>Here's a paragraph</p>
```

Now, say I have a reference to the second `<p>` element. What is the best way to insert html before this tag? (Keeping in mind that the HTML that I want to insert will become a Ckeditor widget after inserting.)

Thank you very much for any help,

Michael

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With <strike>the current API it is not possible to insert HTML string at the specific position without involving selection</strike> (**EDIT**: since CKEditor 4.5.0 it is possible – read below), because the [`editor.insertHtml`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml) method inserts in the selection position. However, if you have a simple situation that your HTML string contains just one element (with some ancestors), then you can easily use [`editor.insertElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertElement) on a lower level, when you can specify range at which you want to insert element:

```
var range = editor.createRange(),
    element = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( elementHtml );

// Place range before the <p> element.
range.setStartAt( elementP, CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START );
// Make sure it's collapsed.
range.collapse( true );

// Insert element at the range position.
editor.editable().insertElement( element, range );
```

As you can see this code uses [`editable.insertElement`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-insertElement), which is used by `editor.insertElement`.

PS. Remember that `insertElement` will not upcast and initialize your widget. You can find more about this here - [CKEditor, initialize widget added with insertElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237845/ckeditor-initialize-widget-added-with-insertelement/20245520#20245520).

### Since 4.5.0

CKEditor 4.5.0 introduced [`editor.editable().insertHtmlIntoRange()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-insertHtmlIntoRange) as well as a `range` parameter for [`editor.insertHtml()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-insertHtml). The latter method is a more high-level one, so it will take care of undo manager and setting selection in place of insertion. The former one is more a low-level method and it only inserts the data.

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing answer. I wish I could upvote you more than once. Thank you very much! I'm sure this will be helpful to others searching for the same thing.

Comment: I updated my answer, because CKEditor 4.5.0 brought some goodies.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!!! but it need to be updated. Also variable elementP is not intialised. Could you update the answer in order to not create a new thread? Thanks :) !!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert an element *between or outside* of the paragraphs 
, the [CKEDITOR.POSITION_BEFORE_START](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-POSITION_BEFORE_START) flag won't work because the element will still be placed *inside* the `<p></p>` node.

However, the [CKEDITOR.dom.node.insertBeforeMe()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.node-method-insertBeforeMe) method will place the new element before any editor node without wrapping it or confining it to a text node.

```
var startRange = editor.getSelection(); //Cursor position
var parent = startRange.getStartElement(); //The parent <p> or <span> of the cursor

var e1 = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml("<h3>Subtitle before paragraphs</h3>");
parent.insertBeforeMe(e1); //Places new node before the specified node
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

its smoothly simple as this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add1").click(function(){
       CKEDITOR.instances.editor2.insertHtml( '<ul><li>Computers & Electronics</li></ul>' );
    });
 });
```