# CKEditor get range to insert HTML at custom location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am working on a module [CKEditor Responsive Plugin](https://github.com/kgaut/drupal-ckeditor-responsive-plugin) for Drupal 7. I would need to insert a piece of HTML at a custom location above the cursor position. Below is the image which shows current cursor position:

[image]

The HTML of above part of the code looks like this:

```
<div class="ckeditor-col-container">
   <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
      <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
         <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
      <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
         <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
      <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
         <p>lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<p><br />
   Sri Ramakrishna Vidya Kendra
</p>
<p></p>
```

The three div's which you see is the location which I now want to insert - that means I need to append my new set of div's below the last child div of the div with class `ckeditor-col-container`

I have gone through this SO link which talks about inserting HTML in given range: [Insert HTML before an element in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547732/insert-html-before-an-element-in-ckeditor)

However, following are the challenges which I was not able to solve:

- Traverse through the DOM above current cursor location to prepare the range with respect to the **nearest div** with class `ckeditor-col-container`
- Get to the end of this (ckeditor-col-container) DOM and prepare range so that the new HTML elements would be inserted inside the scope of `ckeditor-col-container`
- The DOM structure above cursor can be nested, but I am interested to find the nearest div with class `ckeditor-col-container` irrespective of the complicated nested DOM structures.

This is relatively easy to achive using jQuery object and traversing through DOM but CKEditor is cryptic with comparatively very less literature. Also point 3 in the above is tricky as a hierarchical datastructure has to be read in a flat fashion.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
The example HTML piece of code which I want to insert is the same div's which you can find above:

lorem ipsum

And the final HTML will be like this:

```
    <div class="ckeditor-col-container">
       <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
          <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
             <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
          <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
             <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
          <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
             <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
       </div>
.
.
.
       <div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">
          <div class="grid-12 twelvecol">
             <p>lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
       </div>
.
.
.
    </div>
    <p><br />
       Sri Ramakrishna Vidya Kendra
    </p>
    <p></p>
```

The new 'inserted' div is the one which is displayed between the dots. I did not find a way to highlight the code when it is code-formatted.

Comment: Can you give an example of the html you would like to insert, and what should be the final html after the insertion?

Comment: @Dekel - I have edited my question above.

Comment: Did you check the answer?

Comment: @Dekel - I did check it but did not try it, I am doing it now! Thanks for the answer, will report my findings to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't do a complete traversing, but I think it can give you a pretty good place to start with.

The general idea is to take the current position of the cursor and start to check if any of the siblings (up and down the DOM tree) is the element we are looking for.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'samplePlugin', {
    icons: 'samplePluginIcon',
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.addCommand( 'samplePlugin', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                // First we need to find where our cursor is
                var selection = editor.getSelection();
                var range = selection.getRanges()[0];

                // We go up and down the DOM tree, so we need the prev and next elements
                var prevNode = range.getPreviousNode();
                var nextNode = range.getNextNode();

                // Save the container we are looking for
                var container = null;
                while (prevNode || nextNode) {
                    while (prevNode && prevNode.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT) {
                        prevNode = prevNode.getPreviousSourceNode();
                    }
                    if (prevNode && prevNode.hasClass('ckeditor-col-container')) {
                        container = prevNode;
                        break;
                    } else if (prevNode) {
                        prevNode = prevNode.getPreviousSourceNode();
                    }
                    while (nextNode && nextNode.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_TEXT) {
                        nextNode = nextNode.getNextSourceNode();
                    }
                    if (nextNode && nextNode.hasClass('ckeditor-col-container')) {
                        container = nextNode;
                        break;
                    } else if (nextNode) {
                        nextNode = nextNode.getNextSourceNode();
                    }
                }
                // In case we found the container we are looking for - just append some HTML to it.
                if (container) {
                    container.appendHtml('<div class="hundred-hundred-fifty-fifty-thirtythree-thirtythree">'+
                                    '<div class="grid-12 twelvecol">'+
                                        '<p>lorem ipsum</p>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                 '</div>')
                }
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'samplePlugin', {
            label: 'samplePlugin',
            command: 'samplePlugin',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Works for me, have awarded you the answer and bounty. However, there is one thing which I think you have missed here. I explicitly want to check and insert the new HTML in the DOM structure above the cursor only. I think your code does not accommodate this yet, any fix for that?

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal, you said you wanted the nearest div, so the code will give you the nearest (whether its before or after your cursor location). If you want only to go up the dom-tree you can remove the parts related to `nextNode`.

Comment: I mentioned "Traverse through the DOM **above current cursor location**" in my question. But anyways, this works for me as of now! Thanks for the help!