# CKEditor 4.3 Widget Richcombo

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I insert a widget when one of the dropdown menu in Richcombo is clicked? I've read the widget tutorial [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1) and API documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api)

I tried something like this, but it didn't work

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('my_plugin', {

    init: function(editor) {

        editor.ui.addRichCombo('my_plugin', {
            label: 'plugin1',

            init: function() {
                this.add('FIRST_NAME', 'FIRST NAME', 'Insert FIRST NAME');
            },

            onclick: function(value) {
                editor.focus();
                editor.widgets.add('widget1', {
                    upcast: function( element ) {
                        // Defines which elements will become widgets.
                        if ( element.hasClass( 'widget1' ) )
                            return true;
                    },    
                });

                editor.setData( '<div class="widget1">foo</div>' );      
            }
        )};
    }
});
```

Comment: Here's a tip: `editor.widgets.add` does not add a widget into the editor editable area, it registers a widget so that the editor knows about the existance of "widget1". There is a nice example here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget - see there they first register the widget so CKE knows such a thing exists. Then they tell how to recognize a HTML node as the widget. After than, when you add matching HTML to the editor, it  automagically converts that HTML node into a widget. Nodes become widgets.

Comment: @Nenotlep Great answer! I've modified my code above. If I understand it correctly, the `.add` should register my `widget1` to the repository, and the `upcast` widget definition specifies that anything in the editor with a `widget` class would be turned into a widget. However, the `editor.widgets.add();` gave me a console error message. It said: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. There has to be some small mistakes somewhere, but I couldn't find it. Do you know why this gave me an error message?