# How to tell if an element is a Widget? (CKEditor)

Tags: ckeditor

Per [CKEditor, initialize widget added with insertElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237845/ckeditor-initialize-widget-added-with-insertelement/20245520#20245520), we are doing an insertElement() and then initializing with initOn(). The problem is that some of the elements we are inserting are not supposed to be widgets and initOn() makes them widgets and the context menu doesn't work right. I am having trouble finding any properties inside the item/element to tell if something is/is not a widget so I can then call initOn().

Cross-posted downstream on Drupal.org here https://www.drupal.org/node/2466297

Comment: I recommend an official [Widget guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1). You should probably define a right [`upcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast) function for your widget (it's a custom widget isn't it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First of all - which element do you mean?

(**Note**: In this section I am assuming that a widget was correctly and fully initialised.)

#### Widget element

A widget can obviously consists of many elements. One of them is called the "[widget element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-property-element)" and this is the element which you "[upcasted](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast)" and which you can later access through `widget.element`.

Since CKEditor 4.5.0 there will be such method available:

```
Widget.isDomWidgetElement = function( node ) {
    return node.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && node.hasAttribute( 'data-widget' );
};
```

You can of course already use this code to check if a given node is a widget element.

#### Widget wrapper

Second important element is the widget's wrapper. It is created during data processing if a widget element was marked to be upcasted or when [`initOn()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-initOn) is called if the widget element wasn't wrapped yet. You can access this element through the [`widget.wrapper`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-property-wrapper) property.

Since CKEditor 4.5.0 there will be a following method available:

```
Widget.isDomWidgetWrapper = function( node ) {
    return node.type == CKEDITOR.NODE_ELEMENT && node.hasAttribute( 'data-cke-widget-wrapper' );
};
```

And again - you can use this code already.

Important note here - since you mention `insertElemet()` in your question. As I explained in [CKEditor, initialize widget added with insertElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237845/ckeditor-initialize-widget-added-with-insertelement/20245520#20245520) `editor#insertElement()` does not trigger data processing. Therefore, element that you insert is inserted as is. This means that the widget wrapper is not created during insertion and will be created once you call `initOn()`.

#### Finding widgets by any element

Many times you want to find a widget instance by some element that you have (any element that can be inside a widget). There's a useful method for that: [`getByElement()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-method-getByElement).

### What should become a widget? Aka - how to deal with `editor.insertElement()`?

You mentioned that you use `editor.insertElement()` and that you don't know which elements are supposed to be widgets. This should never happen. `editor.insertElement()` is a quite low level method which will not do all the data processing and upcasting magic which `editor.insertHtml()` does. It means that it is supposed to be used in a different case - when you want to insert exactly the element that you have.

For instance, your table plugin is building a table structure to be inserted into editor. You know that the table is empty, so you control every bit of it (other plugins should not interfere here). It is also important that it's the table's plugin decision, not e.g. a template's plugin decision. The table's plugin control the table feature, while the template plugin only uses tables. So in such case, when you have a full control, you can use `editor.insertElement()`. Then you always know what you insert and what is supposed to become a widget.

In all other scenarios you should use `editor.insertHtml()`, so the whole data processing layer is triggered. Thanks to it other features like the widgets system, the link plugin (which turns empty anchors into fake objects), etc. can prepare the data that you insert to be fully editable and integrated.

### Tl;dr

If your plugin knows what it does, it can use `editor.insertElement()`, but since it knows what it does it will know which inserted element must become a widget.

If your plugin does not fully control the situation, then you should use the `editor.isertHtml()` method which is far more automated and will turn proper elements into widgets based on the upcast callbacks.