# How to force CKEditor to process widgets when setting the HTML of an element

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have create a simple CKEditor widget that highlights the elements that have the class "pink".

I have also added a "Pinkify" button to the toolbar, which replaces the HTML of the selected element with some other elements that have the class "pink".

What I observe when I click the button is that widgets are not created for the freshly inserted elements. However, when I toggle between Source mode and WYSISYG mode, the widgets get created.

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfox1984/a6qyn2hL/) and its code:

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('ck', {
  allowedContent: true,
  extraPlugins: 'pink'
});

CKEDITOR.plugins.add('pink', {
  requires: 'widget',
  init: function(editor) {
    editor.widgets.add('pinkwidget', {
      upcast: function(element) {
        return element.hasClass('pink');
      }
    });

    editor.addCommand('pinkify', {
      editorFocus: 1,
      exec: function(editor) {
        var selection = editor.getSelection(),
          selectedElement = selection.getStartElement();
        if (selectedElement) {
          selectedElement.setHtml("Let's have some <span class=\"pink\">pink</span> widget here!");
          editor.widgets.checkWidgets(); // needed?
        }
      }
    });

    editor.ui.addButton('pinkify', {
      label: 'Pinkify',
      command: 'pinkify'
    });
  },
  onLoad: function() {
    CKEDITOR.addCss('.cke_widget_pinkwidget { background: pink; }');
  }
});
```

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20237845/1010492) on Stackoverflow, but I can't get it to work with `setHtml` called on an element. Can you suggest how to modify the code so that widgets get created as soon as the HTML is updated?

Comment: Not getting much love here. Logged a ticket to the CKEditor team on GitHub: [Widgets not initialised after calling setHtml on an element](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CKEditor team, it is normal that [`CKEDITOR.dom.element.setHtml`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dom_element.html#method-setHtml) does not instanciate widgets (see [Widgets not initialised after calling setHtml on an element](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2204#issuecomment-402976337)).

So the workaround they gave me was to rewrite the code that insert HTML in place of the selected element to:

```js
if (selectedElement) {
    selectedElement.setHtml("");
    editor.insertHtml("Let's have some <span class=\"pink\">pink</span> widget here!");
}
```

For those like me who didn't know, [`editor.insertHTML`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertHtml) inserts HTML code **into the currently selected position** in the editor in WYSIWYG mode.

[Updated jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/07vx8kn5/).